# Ignoring browser-related variables while frontend testing react + redux app

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, mocha.js, redux

I'm currently using mocha for frontend testing my react/redux app.

It seems like whenever there are browser-related variables in my functions, the test fails.

For example, one of my functions looks like this:

```
export const loginUserSuccess = (token, user) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token); // browser-related variable here
    return {
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
            token: token,
            user: user
        }
    }
}
```

Note my use of `localStorage`. This variable is obviously not available while testing, so any test that happens to trigger the `loginUserSuccess` action never passes. To be honest I don't need to test the localStorage logic at all -- I just want the action to return the correct thing. But even if I do something like this:

`if (localStorage) localStorage.setItem('token', token);`

*I still get an error saying localStorage is undefined.* How can I get the testing module to ignore certain variables?

Another example is when an action calls the global `window`. When making API calls, I have my action look at the window to see where to send its requests:

```
export const createUserInAuthStore = (username, password) => {

    let url = `${window.__BASE_URL__}/auth/user/` // look at the window here
    let data = { username, password }

    return request
      .post(url)
      .type('form')
      .send(data)
      .end()
      .then((response) => {
        return {
            token: response.body.token,
            username
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error))
}
```

Obviously mocha complains that window is undefined on line 3. But even if I fix that line to this:

`let baseurl = window ? window.__BASE_URL__ : 'api.dockerhost'`

mocha continues to throw an error.

**TL;DR**: Is there a way to ignore or replace browser-related variables when testing?

Comment: you could try replacing window.localStorage with some mock version, which just sets a local variable (or discards it if you don't need it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mocha, all globally available variables are prefixed with `global`. So to mock your `localStorage`, you can do this

```
global.localStorage = {
    setItem: function () {}
}
```

and for your window, you can do this:

```
global.window = {
    __BASE_URL__: "/bla/whatever"
}
```

And don't forget to delete them again afterwards to avoid influencing other tests (I usually do that in the `afterEach()` function).